# Appropriate Windows version for Mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, windows, mysql-5.5

I have a [HP ProLiant DL380 G5](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01096198&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=3239517&prodTypeId=12169) server and I would like to install mysql on it .

My questions are:

1. Which MySQL version should I install from [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) for better performance, 32 bit or 64 bit?
2. Which version of **Windows** should I install on server for better performance: 2003, 2008, XP, or 7?

Comment: Don't run windows, run Linux! /end tongue-in-cheek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 64 bit always. You do understand 32 vs 64 bit generally?
2. Windows Server 2008 R2 of course. Windows 7 is desktop, Windows 2003 is obsolete

Have you considered Linux though?